# How to rounded every tr in table

Tags: html, css, html-table, rounded-corners

I have this code but I can't round every `<tr>` in a table or in the child table.

I'm a backend developer and I have some basic knowledge of HTML, and CSS.

My code result:

[image: my code result]

The intended result:

[image: result is something like this]

```css
.table-curved {
  border-collapse: separate;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  background-color: #424250;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.table-curved {
  border: solid #424250 1px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-left: 0px;
}

.table-curved tr {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 26px;
  border-collapse: seperate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  background-position-x: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: background .1s;
}


/* .table-curved tr:hover {
            background:#eee;
        } */

.table-curved th {
  border-top: none;
}

.table-curved th:first-child {
  border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
}

.table-curved th:last-child {
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
}

.table-curved th:only-child {
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.table-curved tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 0;
}

.table-curved tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 6px;
}

.table-curved td:first-child:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
  position: absolute;
}

.table-curved td.red:before {
  background: red;
}

.table-curved td.green:before {
  background: green;
}

.table-curved td.blue:before {
  background: blue;
}

.table-curved td.orange:before {
  background: orange;
}

.table-curved td:first-child {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.table-curved td {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #424250;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.table-curved .child td {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #393943;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #424250;
}

.header-tr {
  background-color: #363640;
}

.body-tr {
  background-color: #393943;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-curved">
  <tr class="header-tr">
    <td class="orange" style="width: 8% !important;">
      وضعیت
    </td>
    <td style="width: 8% !important;">
      مهلت انجام
    </td>
    <td style="width: 8% !important;">
      نفر ساعت
    </td>
    <td style="width: 30% !important;">
      گام
    </td>
    <td style="width: 25% !important;">
      عنوان
    </td>
    <td style="width: 19% !important;">
      منشا
    </td>
    <td style="width: 2% !important;">
      ردیف
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="body-tr">
    <td colspan="4" style="padding-left: 0;">
      <table class="table-curved child">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="orange" style="width: 15% !important;"> وضعیت</td>
            <td style="width: 15% !important;">مهلت انجام </td>
            <td style="width: 15% !important;"> نفر ساعت </td>
            <td style="width: 55% !important;">گام</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="orange"> وضعیت</td>
            <td>مهلت انجام </td>
            <td> نفر ساعت </td>
            <td>گام</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>کد نویسی نرم افزار باک 21 با زبان ++C برای افزایش سرعت و کارایی برنامه</h4>
      <label>1401/10/15</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>UB</h4>
      <label>1401/10/15</label>
      <br>
      <button>1</button><button>2</button><button>3</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      #1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The first `<tr>` is rounded but I can't add this for another `<tr>`. I even added `border-radius` to the `<tr>` but nothing changed.

Comment: You can't apply border-radius on tr tag. Only td is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding additional classes like:

```css
td{border: 1px solid red; padding:5px}

.td-first{
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
.td-last{
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="td-first" style="width: 15% !important;"> وضعیت</td>
            <td style="width: 15% !important;">مهلت انجام </td>
            <td style="width: 15% !important;"> نفر ساعت </td>
            <td class="td-last" style="width: 55% !important;">گام</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="td-first"> وضعیت</td>
            <td>مهلت انجام </td>
            <td> نفر ساعت </td>
            <td class="td-last">گام</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```